# C# shape hierarchy programming language

Tags: c#, hierarchy, abstract, shapes

Create an application that uses an array of Shape references to objects of each concrete class in the hierarchy. The application should print a text description
of the object to which each array element refers. Also, in the loop that processes all the shapes in the array, determine whether each shape is a TwoDimensionalShape or a ThreeDimensionalShape. If a shape is a TwoDimensionalShape, display its area. If a shape is a ThreeDimensionalShape, display its area and volume.

I am a real newbie here, I'm really lost doing this. Please, could someone help me with this. Thank You.

Comment: Please show some effort beyond copying and pasting your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck on this one as well, but after finding this abstract class tutorial on Youtube, it all became clear: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwKOMfsYyxo

The question in the textbook wasn't very clear on what needs to abstract but when you look at the context, Shape, TwoDimensionalShape, and ThreeDimensionalShape have to all be abstract and contain abstract methods for Area and Volume within them. Though the trick that I discovered was that once you declare an abstract method, you don't have to declare that method in derived abstract classes until a concrete class implements them.

Comment: The textbook is "C# How to Program" by Deitel (1st edition). I answered this so others can get help with this particular issue since when I did my own search I found this question.